# Create contingency table that displays the frequency distribution of pairs of variables

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, crosstab, contingency

I want to create a contingency table that displays the frequency distribution of pairs of variables. Here is an example dataset:

```
mm <- matrix(0, 5, 6)
df <- data.frame(apply(mm, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1)))
colnames(df) <- c("Horror", "Thriller", "Comedy", "Romantic", "Sci.fi", "gender")
```

All variables are binary with 1 indicating either the presence of specfic movie type or the male gender. In the end, I would like to have the table that counts the presence of different movie types under specific gender. Something like this:

```
           male female
Horror      1      1
Thriller    1      3
Comedy      2      2
Romantic    0      0
Sci.fi      2      0
```

I know I can create two tables of different movie types for male and female individually (see TarJae's answer here [Create count table under specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086033/create-count-table-under-specific-condition/70086621#70086621)) and `cbind` them later but I would like to do it in one chunk of code. How to achieve this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
sapply(split(df, df$gender), function(x) colSums(x[names(x)!="gender"]))    

#>          0 1
#> Horror   1 1
#> Thriller 1 3
#> Comedy   0 0
#> Romantic 0 0
#> Sci.fi   1 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this base R solution @tjebo!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -gender, names_to = "type") %>%
  mutate(gender = fct_recode(as.character(gender),Male = "0",Female = "1")) %>% 
  group_by(gender,type) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = gender,values_from = sum)
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  type      Male Female
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Comedy       0      1
2 Horror       1      3
3 Romantic     1      1
4 Sci.fi       1      1
5 Thriller     1      1
```

The second line is optional but allows to get the levels for the variable `gender`.

Comment: Thank you @Maël. That's very nice use of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`. If no other answers, I will accept yours

Comment: Thanks. I added a line in the code if you want the levels for the variable `gender`.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below a reprex with an alternative solution using `data.table` and `magrittr` (for the pipes), also in one chunk.

**Reprex**

- Your data (I set a seed for reproducibility)

```r
set.seed(452)
mm <- matrix(0, 5, 6)
df <- data.frame(apply(mm, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1)))
colnames(df) <- c("Horror", "Thriller", "Comedy", "Romantic", "Sci.fi", "gender")
df
#>   Horror Thriller Comedy Romantic Sci.fi gender
#> 1      0        1      1        0      0      0
#> 2      0        0      0        0      1      0
#> 3      1        0      1        1      0      1
#> 4      0        1      0        0      0      1
#> 5      0        1      0        0      0      1
```

- Code in one chunk

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # for the pipes!

df %>% 
  transpose(., keep.names = "rn") %>% 
  setDT(.) %>% 
  {.[,  .(rn = rn,
         male = rowSums(.[,.SD, .SDcols = .[, .SD[.N]] == 1]),
         female = rowSums(.[,.SD, .SDcols = .[, .SD[.N]] == 0]))][rn !="gender"]}
```

- Output

```r
#>          rn male female
#> 1:   Horror    1      0
#> 2: Thriller    2      1
#> 3:   Comedy    1      1
#> 4: Romantic    1      0
#> 5:   Sci.fi    0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @lovalery! I was actually wondering if there is any `data.table` answers